# Task and Parallel.Invoke in a library, is it a bad idea to use it?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I have read that to do a fake async method in this way it is a bad idea:

```
public int myMethodSyn()
{
    //sync operations

    return result;
}

public async int myMethodAsync()
{
    return await Task.Run(myMethodSync);
}
```

One of the reasons that I have read it is because for example, ASP can have scalability problems with this kind of libraries because tasks use the thread pool and ASP need the thread pool to attend each call. So the library can consume all the threads of the thread pool al block ASP. SO it is better allow to the client decides how to use the thread pool.

If am not wrong, Parallel.Invoke use the thread pool too to run methods in parallel, so I guess that if I use a method in my library that uses parallel.Invoke, or parallel.Foreach or any of this ways to run code in parallel, I would have the same problem. Is it true?

My idea is to run two mthods in parallel because they are indepent and I could get a better performance if I run them in parallel. So I would have somthing like that:

```
public int myMainMethodSync()
{
    int result01 = myMethod01Sync();
    int result02 = myMethod02Sync();
    return result01 + result02;
}

private void myMethod01Sync()
{
}

private void myMethod02Sync()
{
}

public int myMainMethodAsync()
{
    Task myTsk01 = Task.Run(myMethod01Sync);
    Task myTsk02 = Task.Run(myMethod02Sync);
    Task.WhenAll(myTsk01, myTsk02);

    return myTsk01.Result + myTsk02.Result;
}

public int Task myMainMethodParallel()
{
    int result01;
    int result02;
    Parallel.Invoke(() => result01 = myMethod01Sync(),
                    () => result02 = myMethod02Sync());

    return result01 + result02;
}
```

The idea is it to have a sync method that run the two methods in sync. So the client who use the library knows that the method will not use thread pool.

Later I have two options to run the methods at the same time, with tasks or with parallel.Invoke.

In the case of the tasks, I am using a fake async methods because I am wraping the sync method inside a task, that use two threads from the threadpool. If I am not wrong, this is not recommended.

The other option it is to use Parallel.Invoke, that uses threads from thread pool too, so I guess it has the same problem that with tasks, so I guess that it is not recommended too.

In my case I would prefer to use task, because I can decide with a condition when to run the method02Sync for example, according to some condiciotion, so I could save the cost to assign a thread to run the second method if I know that it is not needed in some cases. I guess in parallel.Invoke this is not possible.

However, I think that in this case, how I implement a sync method too, I let the client to choose the method that it considerates better in its case, so really it is a bad option to use tasks in the async method?

If both solutions are bad, tasks and Parallel.Invloke, then it is not recommended to run parallel code in libraries and only use it in the top level, in the UI or client of the library? Because I guess that in this case the use of parallel is very restrictive, because in the top level, in the UI, it is not possible to use parallel if it decides it is possible because tell to library use threads or not, because it wouldn't have parallel methods.

In sumary, is my solution, expose sync and async methods a bad idea? is it bad idea to use task or parallel code in the libraries? If one of them it is better option, which one?

Thanks.

Comment: How long does each of the methods you invoke usually take? How much speedup does running them in parallel give you?

Comment: My question it is more about trying to know the differences between tasks and Parallel.Invoke and the best way to develop libraries that use parallel, if it is a good idea to develop libraries that use parallelism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is my solution, expose sync and async methods a bad idea?

Let me reformulate the question to make it more general:

> Is it a good idea to expose two versions of a method with different performance characteristics?

I think that most of the time, it is a bad idea. The API of your library should be clear, you should not make the users of your library constantly keep choosing between the two options. I think it's your responsibility as a library author to make the decision, even if it's going to be the wrong one for some of your users.

If the differences between the two options are dramatic, you could consider some approach that lets your users to choose between them. But I think having two separate methods is the wrong choice, something like an optional parameter would be a better approach, because it means there is a clear default.

The one exception I can think of is if the signatures of the two methods are different, like with truly async methods. But I don't think that applies to your use of `Task`s to parallelize CPU-bound methods.

> Is it bad idea to use task or parallel code in the libraries?

I think you should use them cautiously. You are right that your users might not be happy if your library uses more resources (here, threads) to make itself faster. On the other hand, most methods of parallelizing code are smart enough that if the amount of available thread pool threads is limited, they will still work fine. So, if you measured that the speedup gained by parallelizing your code is significant, I think it's okay to do it.

> If one of them it is better option, which one?

I think this is more a matter of which one you prefer as a matter of code style. The performance characteristics of `Parallel.Invoke()` with two actions and synchronously waiting for two `Task`s should be comparable.

Though keep in mind that your call to `Task.WhenAll` doesn't really do anything, since `WhenAll` *returns* a `Task` that completes when all its component `Task`s complete. You could instead use `Task.WaitAll`, but I'm not sure what would be the point, since you're already implicitly waiting for both `Task`s by acessing their `Result`s.